# How to populate/refresh a grid based on some condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, aspxgridview

I have a grid which is getting values from numerous tables, views based on some conditions.
These tables are getting updated frequently and those updated fields get populated in my grid as well. Now my grid has a status field (open/closed), if the status is closed that row should be frozen and will not get updated even the tables will get updated.

This is an aspx page and the code is in controller, the database query handled in Entity Framework.
I am struggling on this over a week. Any insight on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to freeze those rows in UI part and when it get refreshed from database the frozen rows will not be touched and remain same?

Comment: if u use aspx grid control,then while binding data source, you can identify row based on status and make it disable. or if you are using angular or jquery for grid, then in script,based on flag,set disable attribute for row tag.

Comment: Thanks @VishalPawar for your reply..I am using aspx grid control. I will try like this.